# acts as taggable on doesn't save tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, tagging, acts-as-taggable-on

I have this model

```
class Unit < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable
end
```

When I write `Unit.first.tag_list = "test"`, I get `=> "test"` as response, but a tag is never saved to my database. Also, when I type `Unit.first.tags` I get an empty array

Any advice?

EDIT: Fixed one error, but the tags still doesnt get saved

Answer (score 0):

Have you try saving the record ?

```
u = Unit.first
u.tag_list = "foo"
u.save

u.reload
u.tag_list
=> ["foo"]
```